# Remove Blog Title in Specific Theme

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to use a functions.php in my child theme to remove the blog title.  Most posts here are for specific themes.  No option I've tried have worked.

I found in header.php where the blog title is called:

```
<?php do_action('et_header_top'); ?>
    <header class="clearfix">
        <hgroup id="logo-area">
            <?php $bloginfo_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
            <h1 id="logo">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $bloginfo_name ); ?>"><?php if ( 'false' == et_get_option( 'flexible_logo_image', 'false' ) || '' == et_get_option( 'flexible_logo' ) ) echo apply_filters( 'et_logo_markup', $bloginfo_name ); else echo '<img src="' . esc_url( et_get_option( 'flexible_logo' ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $bloginfo_name ) . '" />'; ?></a>
            </h1>
            <h2><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>
```

What do I put in functions.php to remove that?

I tried

```
`function remove_stuff()
{
remove_action('Fable_header','Fable_bloginfotitle',);
remove_action('Fable_header','Fable_bloginfodescription',);
}
add_action('init','remove_stuff');

?>`
```

with no change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the blog title without deleting the code, you can comment it out. This helps reduce problems. If you want to put the blog title back later, you can easily put it out if it is commented out, but if you delete the text then you can't display the title.

Commenting out works like this: wrap your code in /* and */. Example: `/* code */`. In your case, you would want to comment out the code like this:

```
<?php do_action('et_header_top'); ?>
<header class="clearfix">
    /* <hgroup id="logo-area">
        <?php $bloginfo_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
        <h1 id="logo">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $bloginfo_name ); ?>"><?php if ( 'false' == et_get_option( 'flexible_logo_image', 'false' ) || '' == et_get_option( 'flexible_logo' ) ) echo apply_filters( 'et_logo_markup', $bloginfo_name ); else echo '<img src="' . esc_url( et_get_option( 'flexible_logo' ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $bloginfo_name ) . '" />'; ?></a>
        </h1>
        <h2><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
    </hgroup> */
```

Comment: Wouldn't using a separate functions.php file in my child theme be better, especially if the theme is updated?

Comment: You should edit the header.php file in your child theme in order to prevent problems with updates. If the header.php is not showing up in your child theme, you need to copy it from the original theme to the child theme with an FTP client. What hosting are you using?

Comment: So you're saying (to ensure I understand)  Copy the header.php file into my child theme folder, and modify it - removing the code above?

Comment: Exactly. Using an FTP, duplicate the header.php into your child theme and then delete the code.